# All surjections onto trivial irrep split equivalent to being reductive

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\Hom{Hom}$Let $ G $ be linear algebraic group over a field $ k $. Is it true that every short exact sequence of algebraic $ G $-representations
$$
0 \to W \to V \to k \to 0 
$$
splits if and only if $ G $ is reductive?

I believe this is true over $ k=\mathbb{C} $.

Here are my thoughts on the direction starting with the assumption that $ G $ is a reductive complex group, and thus linearly reductive. Since $ G $ is linearly reductive then $ V $ and $ W $ are completely reducible so $ V= \bigoplus_\rho m_\rho \rho $ and $ W= \bigoplus_\rho n_\rho \rho $ with $ \rho $ all irreducible.  Then
$$
V/W= \bigoplus_\rho (m_\rho-n_\rho) \rho \cong \mathbb{C}
$$
so we must have $ m_\rho=n_\rho $ for all nontrivial $ \rho $ and $ m_\rho=1+n_\rho $ when $ \rho $ is the trivial irrep. Let $ 1 $ denote the trivial irrep. Let $ W_1 $ denote the $ 1 $ isotypic subspace of $ W $ and let $ V_1 $ denote the $ 1 $ isotypic subspace of $ V $. Recall $ m_1=n_1+1 $ so $ W_1 $ has codimension $ 1 $ in $ V_1 $. Since $ G $ is linearly reductive we can take a complement of $ W_1 $ in $ V_1 $, call it $ U $
$$
V_1 = W_1 \oplus U
$$
The map $ k \to U $ is the desired splitting.

Justin Bloom [points out](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/462255/all-surjections-onto-trivial-irrep-split-equivalent-to-being-reductive#comment1199368_462255) that if we allow non-algebraic infinite dimensional representations then there are easy counterexamples. For example take $ V $ to be the space of all finitely supported function $ f: k \to k $ with the action of $ G=(k,+) $ permuting $ k $ by translation. And let $ W $ be the submodule of $ f $ such that $ 0=\sum_{x \in k} f(x) $ and let the map $ V \to k $ be given by $ f \mapsto \sum_{x \in k} f(x) $. Then $ V $ has no trivial subrepresentions, so the map $ V \to k $ does not split.

Comment: Your definition of representation must include finite dimensional here. Otherwise any infinite, transitive $G$-set $X$ has an infinite dimensional permutation representation $kX$, and taking $x \in X$ to $1 \in k$ is surjective but doesn't split.

Comment: @JustinBloom: Those are not algebraic representations.  Algebraic representations are not necessarily finite dimensional, but they are unions of finite dimensional representations.

Comment: @AndyPutman good point! I'll just keep things as they are then

Comment: TeX note: `\oplus` is semantically only a binary operation, so please use `\bigoplus` for an indexed sum ($\bigoplus_\rho m_\rho\rho$ in place of $\oplus_\rho m_\rho\rho$).  I edited accordingly.  (Fairly irrelevantly, I'll take this opportunity to whine: I have seen at least one otherwise excellent book where, bizarrely, the `\big` and non-`\big` operators are switched, writing, for example, $V \bigoplus W$ versus $\oplus_\rho m_\rho\rho$.)

Comment: @LSpice I was looking back at the proof I wrote in my question, and I started wondering if it could be a problem that the trivial subrep of $ V $ I prove the existence of might be contained in $ W $ in which case it couldn't be used as the image of a splitting. How does the proof look to you?

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/462255/all-surjections-onto-trivial-irrep-split-equivalent-to-being-reductive#comment1199600_462255), just note that, if $W = \bigoplus_\rho n_\rho\rho$, then $n_\rho \le m_\rho$ for all $\rho$, and $V/W = \bigoplus_\rho (m_\rho - n_\rho)\rho$.  Then run the whole proof on $V/W$ rather than $V$ to see that $m_1 - n_1 > 0$.

Comment: Thank you! I've made the appropriate adjustment

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are asking whether an algebraic group is reductive if and only if it is linearly reductive. This is true in characteristic zero, but in nonzero characteristic, tori are the only connected linearly reductive algebraic groups. See Milne, Algebraic Groups, 2017, 12.56 for precise statements and references.

Comment: Could you say a bit more about how the condition I describe is equivalent to being linearly reductive? Also the pdf I found for Milne 2017 https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/iAG200.pdf  has numbered items in chapter 12 that only go up to 12.43. Am I accessing the wrong reference?

Comment: Milne, J. S. Algebraic groups. The theory of group schemes of finite type over a field
Cambridge Stud. Adv. Math., 170, Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 2017. vi+644 pp. ISBN:978-1-107-16748-3

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/462255/all-surjections-onto-trivial-irrep-split-equivalent-to-being-reductive#comment1199566_462280), yes, there are significant changes in numbering between the last online version and the published version.  (I don't remember how many are due to re-ordering, and how many due to new or removed content.)